# Как вытянуть третий символ из строки

Tags: php, строки

Как правильней и в чем различия

```
$str='12345';

echo $str[2];

echo $str{2};

echo substr($str, 2, 1);
```

Comment: Обращаться к одному символу через substr это по-моему извращение. В первых двух случаях разницы особо нет.

Comment: $str[2] это вроде часть массива? поправте если не прав

Comment: В PHP строка является массивом символов, при условии что это строка не массива или объекта, а просто переменной

Answer (score 1):

первый способ проще и тем самым лучше, а чтобы судить о разнице нужно курить исходники ПХП.